# I need to have my site visitors post comments even if they are not logged in as a member

Tags: 7, comments

I need to have my site visitors post comments even if they are not logged in as a member in my drupal 7 site. How do I do that? or is it better to have them sign up so they can post comments?

Comment: Check permission settings..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the "anonymous user" role permissions to post comments. Go to `admin/people/permissions` and look for the Comment section. Check the box for "Post comments" for the Anonymous user role, then save the settings.

I would not suggest this unless you have good anti-spam measures in place. You can search drupal.org for modules in the [Spam Prevention category](http://drupal.org/project/modules?filters=tid%3A7266%20drupal_core%3A103%20bs_project_sandbox%3A0&solrsort=sis_project_release_usage%20desc) to help with that. Otherwise, I would require users to sign in before posting comments.

Note that even when requiring users to sign in to post comments, you'll still likely run into spam. Couldn't hurt to look into the list of modules linked to above.

Comment: great! looking into this anti-spam modules. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the Disqus remotely hosted comments system. Users do need to log in to that - but not to your site. They can use a number of other sites they already have accounts in like Facebook or Google.